# CodeIgniter 2.2.0 HMAC mismatch error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmac

UPDATE: Even after downloading the "fixed" 2.2.0, update log files are still filling up with:

> Session: HMAC mismatch. The session cookie data did not match what was
>   expected.

After upgrading from CodeIgniter 2.1.3 to 2.2.0 I am getting the error:

> Session: HMAC mismatch. The session cookie data did not match what was
>   expected.

The Mcrypt extension is enabled. If I set $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE; (not an option for production) there is no error. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the exact same error. The only difference is that I upgraded from 2.1.4 to 2.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CI_Input->_sanitize_globals() function sometimes break encrypted session
to fix this problem, I changed /system/core/Input.php (version 2.2, line 636)

```
$_COOKIE[$this->_clean_input_keys($key)] = $this->_clean_input_data($val);
```

to

```
if(!(config_item('sess_encrypt_cookie') === TRUE) || $key!=config_item('sess_cookie_name'))
    $_COOKIE[$this->_clean_input_keys($key)] = $this->_clean_input_data($val);
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming this was a framework issue. https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/3094#issuecomment-51899465

Answer (score 3):

Re-download the CI 2.2 archive, it was re-tagged and replaced.

Comment: don't download it from the official website, download it from github release

Comment: ... I was the one to give you the github link. You just don't know how to clear your browser's download cache.

Answer (score 1):

in system/libraries/Sessions.php function _set_cookie function change:

```
if ($this->sess_encrypt_cookie == TRUE)
{
    $cookie_data = $this->CI->encrypt->encode($cookie_data);
}
else
{
    // if encryption is not used, we provide an md5 hash to prevent userside tampering
    $cookie_data .= hash_hmac('sha1', $cookie_data, $this->encryption_key);
}
```

to:

```
if ($this->sess_encrypt_cookie == TRUE)
{
    $cookie_data = $this->CI->encrypt->encode($cookie_data);
}

$cookie_data .= hash_hmac('sha1', $cookie_data, $this->encryption_key);
```

to see if it works.

see: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/3086

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the above correction, I needed to change the following line:

```
if ($key === $sess_cookie_name && config_item('sess_encrypt_cookie'))
```

To:

```
if ($key === config_item('cookie_prefix') . $sess_cookie_name
    && config_item('sess_encrypt_cookie'))
```

Hope it helps,
Regards.

Comment: Please update your answer explain why your code is working.

Comment: The patch provided does not respect the cookie prefix.